# Convertir una fecha en formato 1-Ene-2017 al formato 01-01-2017

Tags: javascript, date

Estoy tratando de convertir una fecha con formato `1-Ene-2017` y sucesivamente con todos los meses, al formato `01-01-2017`.

Esta fecha la obtengo de un campo llamado `hidFechaFinal` con el siguiente código:

```
function validaFechasAsignacion(){
    var fecha_f = document.getElementById("hidFechaFinal").value;

    if(typeof fecha_f === 'undefined' || fecha_f == null || fecha_f == ""){
        alert("Seleccione la fecha final.");
        return false;
    }

    var fechaFinal = new Date(fecha_f); //AQUI HAGO LA CONVERSION DE LA FECHA
    alert("Fecha Final: " + fechaFinal); //AQUI IMPRIME InvalidDate
}
```

Cuando ejecuto esta función el `alert` muestra el mensaje:

> Fecha Final: InvalidDate

Sospecho que es porque el mes esta abreviado en español.

Comment: Es una forma larga pero y si haces un switch con los nombres para convertir una variable a numero y así agregarla ala fecha? No se si sea la mejor solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora de trabajar con fechas yo uso la librería [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Una solución a tu problema usando `momentjs` podría ser la siguente:

```js
function validaFechasAsignacion(){
    var fecha_f = document.getElementById("hidFechaFinal").value;

    // Formato 1-Ene-2017
    var fecha = moment(fecha_f, 'D-MMM-YYYY', true);
    if(!fecha.isValid()){
        alert("Seleccione la fecha final.");
        return false;
    }

    alert("Fecha Final: " + fecha.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/locale/es.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hidFechaFinal" placeholder="Ej: 1-Ene-2017"/>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="validaFechasAsignacion()">Validar</button>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, sin embargo requiero que sea con JavaScript, ya que necesito que funcione con IE6, y creo que la librería momentjs no es compatible con el mismo.